# Draw a mean indexed bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

How to draw the following graph showing the difference against the average using matplotlib, searborn, Plotly or with any other framework?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I have found that some calls this plot [`Mean indexed bar chart`](https://www.reddit.com/r/visualization/comments/9o09ny/how_is_this_graph_called_showing_the_difference/). Using seaborn, it can be using a code like the following:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white", context="talk")

f, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5), sharex=True)


mean = df.mean()
y2 = mean - df["your column"]
sns.barplot(x=dfCopy.index, y=y2, palette="deep", ax=ax1)
ax1.axhline(0, color="k", clip_on=False)
ax1.set_ylabel("Diverging")

# Finalize the plot
sns.despine(bottom=True)
plt.setp(f.axes, yticks=[])
plt.tight_layout(h_pad=2)
```

Comment: If you are going to post an answer to your  own question, at least make it reproducible providing the data and final outcome.

Comment: It's reproducible. Just use your own dataset and column you want to consider against the mean.